# Html Form method reposition for php $_POST using

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have php file with modals ,the problem is that isset($_POST['enregistrer']) is not working in php and i think because of Form methode in html,please help./

/1-the problem is just in php and html,the rest is fine.

/2-there's 4 modals id=MyModal1,2,3 and 4

/3-4 forms method="POST" in modal body of each modal
here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
 
<?php

  $date=date('Y-m-d');
  $date3=date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date . "+3 months") );
  $date6=date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date . "+6 months") );
  $date12=date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date . "+12 months") );
 



  ?>
  <?php
  
         if(isset($_POST['enregistrer'])){
        
      $nom=$_POST['nom_client'];
      $prenom=$_POST['pernomclient'];
      $date_naissance=$_POST['datenaiss'];
      $lieu_naissance=$_POST['lieunaiss'];
      $commune=$_POST['commune'];
      $dayra=$_POST['daira'];
      $willaya=$_POST['wilaya'];
      $proffession=$_POST['proffesion'];

      echo $nom;
      echo $prenom;
      echo $date_naissance;
      echo $lieu_naissance;
      echo $commune;
      echo $dayra;
      echo $willaya;
      echo $proffession;
 
    
  }else {
   
    echo "failed";
  }
 
              ?>

    <title>assurence</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
 <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assurance1css.css">

</head>


<body>
 
<div class="button">
  <img src="lll.jpg" class="rounded" width="170px" height="170px">

    <button type="submit" name="suivantn" class="btn button1 " data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">

      Nouveau-Client
     </button>
  
      <button type="button" class="btn button1 " data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
      Ancien Client
     </button>

</div>

 

   <!-- information de client -->
  <div class="modal" id="myModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
    
        <!-- Modal Header -->
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title">Informations personnelle </h4>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        </div>
        <form  method="POST" class="needs-validation" novalidate>
        <!-- Modal body -->
        <div class="modal-body">
          
            <p> --------------------------------------------------------- </p>
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="male"> Mr
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Meme
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="unknown" > Melle
<p> --------------------------------------------------------- </p>
                        

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="nauto">Nom  du client:</label>

    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nauto" placeholder="Entrer le Nom  du client" name="nom_client"  required >

    <div class="valid-feedback">Valide.</div>
    <div class="invalid-feedback">Veuillez remplir ce champ.</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="nauto">Prenom du client :</label>
 
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="dateverif" placeholder="Entrer le Prenom du client" name="pernomclient"  required >
  
    <div class="valid-feedback">Valide.</div>
    <div class="invalid-feedback">Veuillez remplir ce champ.</div>
  </div>

 <div class="form-group">
    <label for="nauto">Date de naissance :</label>

    <input type="Date" class="form-control" id="datefin" placeholder=" " name="datenaiss" value="<?php echo $date; ?>"
 required >
    <div class="valid-feedback">Valide.</div>
    <div class="invalid-feedback">Veuillez remplir ce champ.</div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="nauto">Lieu de naissance:</label>
 
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nauto" placeholder="Entrer le Lieu de naissance" name="lieunaiss"  required >
 
    <div class="valid-feedback">Valide.</div>
    <div class="invalid-feedback">Veuillez remplir ce champ.</div>
  </div>



 <div class="form-group">
    <label for="nauto">Commune du client:</label>
    
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nauto" placeholder="Entrer la Commune du client" name="commune"  required >
 
    <div class="valid-feedback">Valide.</div>
    <div class="invalid-feedback">Veuillez remplir ce champ.</div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="nauto">Daira du client:</label>
 
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nauto" placeholder="Entrer la Daira du client" name="daira"  required >
  
    <div class="valid-feedback">Valide.</div>
    <div class="invalid-feedback">Veuillez remplir ce champ.</div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="nauto">Willaya du client:</label>
   
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nauto" placeholder="Entrer la Willaya du client" name="wilaya"  required >
 
    <div class="valid-feedback">Valide.</div>
    <div class="invalid-feedback">Veuillez remplir ce champ.</div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="nauto">Sa proffesion:</label>
   
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nauto" placeholder="Entrer Sa proffesion" name="proffesion"  required >
 
    <div class="valid-feedback">Valide.</div>
    <div class="invalid-feedback">Veuillez remplir ce champ.</div>
  </div>


<script>
// Disable form submissions if there are invalid fields
(function() {
  'use strict';
  window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    // Get the forms we want to add validation styles to
    var forms = document.getElementsByClassName('needs-validation');
    // Loop over them and prevent submission
    var validation = Array.prototype.filter.call(forms, function(form) {
      form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
        if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
          event.preventDefault();
          event.stopPropagation();
        }
        form.classList.add('a été validé');
      }, false);
    });
  }, false);
})();
</script>
        </div>
       
        <!-- Modal footer -->
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <h4 class="modal-title text-left "> .</h4>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"  name="suivant1" data-toggle="modal" data-dismiss="modal" data-target="#myModal2">Suivant</button>
        </div>
    </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>




  <!-- Permis -->
  <div class="modal" id="myModal2">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
      
        <!-- Modal Header -->
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title">Permis :</h4>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        </div>
      <form method="POST" class="needs-validation" novalidate>
        <!-- Modal body -->
        
        <div class="modal-body">
          
                        

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="nauto">NUM-Permi:</label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="nauto" placeholder="Entrer le NUM-Permi" name="numpermis"  required >
    <div class="valid-feedback">Valide.</div>
    <div class="invalid-feedback">Veuillez remplir ce champ.</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="nauto">Date Obtention :</label>
    <input type="Date" class="form-control" id="dateverif" placeholder=" " name="dateobt"   required >
    <div class="valid-feedback">Valide.</div>
    <div class="invalid-feedback">Veuillez remplir ce champ.</div>
  </div>


    
  
 <div class="form-group">
    <label for="nauto">Deliver le :</label>
    <input type="Date" class="form-control" id="datefin" placeholder=" " name="delivre"  required="" >
    <div class="valid-feedback">Valide.</div>
    <div class="invalid-feedback">Veuillez remplir ce champ.</div>
  </div>

<div>
  <p><u><strong> Permis Categorie</strong></u> </p>
<select >
            <option id="one"><strong>Type A </strong></option>
            <option id="two"><strong>Type B </strong></option>
            <option id="three"><strong>Type C </strong></option>
        </select>



</div>





<script>
// Disable form submissions if there are invalid fields
(function() {
  'use strict';
  window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    // Get the forms we want to add validation styles to
    var forms = document.getElementsByClassName('needs-validation');
    // Loop over them and prevent submission
    var validation = Array.prototype.filter.call(forms, function(form) {
      form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
        if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
          event.preventDefault();
          event.stopPropagation();
        }
        form.classList.add('a été validé');
      }, false);
    });
  }, false);
})();
</script>
        </div>
        
        <!-- Modal footer -->
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <h4 class="modal-title text-left "> .</h4>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="suivant2" data-toggle="modal" data-dismiss="modal" data-target="#myModal3">Suivant</button>
        </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


<div class="modal" id="myModal3">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
      




        <!-- Modal Header -->
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title">Durée :</h4>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>

        </div>
         <form  method="POST" class="needs-validation" novalidate>
        <!-- Modal body -->
        <div class="modal-body">

         
                    

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="nauto">Durée :</label>
    <select onclick="modal1()" id="durée">
  <option value="volvo">3mois</option>
  <option value="saab">6mois</option>
  <option value="mercedes">12mois</option>
  
</select>


<div class="form-group">
    <label for="nauto">Effet:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="eff" name="Effet"  required readonly>
    <div class="valid-feedback">Valide.</div>
    <div class="invalid-feedback">Veuillez remplir ce champ.</div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="nauto">Expiration</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exp"  name="Expiration"  required readonly >
    <div class="valid-feedback">Valide.</div>
    <div class="invalid-feedback">Veuillez remplir ce champ.</div>
  </div>
</div>




<script>
// Disable form submissions if there are invalid fields
(function() {
  'use strict';
  window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    // Get the forms we want to add validation styles to
    var forms = document.getElementsByClassName('needs-validation');
    // Loop over them and prevent submission
    var validation = Array.prototype.filter.call(forms, function(form) {
      form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
        if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
          event.preventDefault();
          event.stopPropagation();
        }
        form.classList.add('a été validé');
      }, false);
    });
  }, false);
})();
</script>

 </div>

        
        <!-- Modal footer -->
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <h4 class="modal-title text-left "> .</h4>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="suivant3" data-toggle="modal" data-dismiss="modal" data-target="#myModal4" >Suivant</button>
        </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

<div class="modal" id="myModal4">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
      
        <!-- Modal Header -->
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title">Information de voiture:</h4>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>

        </div>
        
        <!-- Modal body -->
        
 <form  method="POST" class="needs-validation" novalidate>
            <div class="modal-body">
         
                    

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="nauto">NUM-dans la serie du type :</label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="nauto" placeholder="Entrer NUM-dans la serie du type " name="numserie"  required >
    <div class="valid-feedback">Valide.</div>
    <div class="invalid-feedback">Veuillez remplir ce champ.</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="nauto">Type :</label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="dateverif" placeholder="Entrer type d voiture" name="typevoi"  required >
    <div class="valid-feedback">Valide.</div>
    <div class="invalid-feedback">Veuillez remplir ce champ.</div>
  </div>
   <div class="form-group">
    <label for="nauto">Marque :</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="dateverif" placeholder="Entrer la marque " name="marque"  required >
    <div class="valid-feedback">Valide.</div>
    <div class="invalid-feedback">Veuillez remplir ce champ.</div>
  </div>
   <div class="form-group">
    <label for="nauto">Aces assise:</label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="dateverif" placeholder="Entrer nmbr d places" name="acesass"  required >
    <div class="valid-feedback">Valide.</div>
    <div class="invalid-feedback">Veuillez remplir ce champ.</div>
  </div>
   <div class="form-group">
    <label for="nauto">Energie:</label>
    <select >
            <option id="ess" value="Ess"><strong>Ess</strong></option>
            <option id="gaz" value="Gaz"><strong>Gaz</strong></option>
            <option id="dsl" value="Dsl"><strong>Dsl</strong></option>
        </select>

  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="nauto">Num d'immatriculation:</label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="dateverif" placeholder="Entrer Num d'immatriculation" name="immatricul"  required >
    <div class="valid-feedback">Valide.</div>
    <div class="invalid-feedback">Veuillez remplir ce champ.</div>
  </div>


<script>
// Disable form submissions if there are invalid fields
(function() {
  'use strict';
  window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    // Get the forms we want to add validation styles to
    var forms = document.getElementsByClassName('needs-validation');
    // Loop over them and prevent submission
    var validation = Array.prototype.filter.call(forms, function(form) {
      form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
        if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
          event.preventDefault();
          event.stopPropagation();
        }
        form.classList.add('a été validé');
      }, false);
    });
  }, false);
})();
</script>
</div>
<!-- Modal footer -->

        <div class="modal-footer">
         

          <h4 class="modal-title text-left "> .</h4>
          
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal" name="enregistrer">Enregistrer</button>
         
        </div>

        </form>

        

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

<script>
function modal1() {
  var select=document.getElementById('durée');
  var strUser = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
  if(strUser=="volvo"){
    document.getElementById("eff").defaultValue = "<?php echo $date;?>";
document.getElementById("exp").defaultValue = "<?php echo $date3;?>";
}
else if(strUser=="saab"){
  document.getElementById("eff").defaultValue = "<?php echo $date;?>";
document.getElementById("exp").defaultValue = "<?php echo $date6;?>";
}
else if(strUser=="mercedes"){
  document.getElementById("eff").defaultValue = "<?php echo $date;?>";
document.getElementById("exp").defaultValue = "<?php echo $date12;?>";
}
}


</script>





</body>





</html>
```

Comment: What's "Not working"? What's the value of this variable and what are expected?

Comment: @FelippeDurate the if(isset) condition in php is always false even when cklicking the submit button  while the name of the button 'enregistrer' is right,

Comment: Do a `print_r($_POST);` at the top of your script to see exactly what is being received. Also learn to use the browser's devtools, paying attention to the network tab, and console. Wouldn't hurt to also turn on all php error/warning/notices as well to tell you about all the other things wrong.

Comment: @IncridibleHat the print_r($_POST); methode output Array ( ) failed,and for browser dev tool im gonna try to use it thnx

Answer (score 0):

I found your `<form>` is missing the **action** attribute. It seems like you want to submit your **form** to the same page. To submit to the same page you need to do this:

```
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post">
```

Here, `$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]` tells you want to submit your **form** to the same page.

Comment: im gonna try it thanx